# Autoincrement won't work inside foreach in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-table

Right now I'm trying to add a feature to my table.

It's being done inside a cshtml C# MVC ASP.NET Enviroment.

```
@{
    dt_Table = ds_Set.Tables[1];
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt_Table.Rows)
    {
        int autoincrement = 0;
        string nombre = dr["Nombre"].ToString();



        <tr>
            <td align="center">@(autoincrement++)</td>
            <td align="center">@nombre</td>
        </tr>

    }
}
```

How do I add auto increment or ++ to the value?
Right now like that it just prints "1" on each row of the table :(

How can I solve this?

Comment: Just declare autoincrement outside of the foreach. You're assigning 0 at each iteration.

Comment: `int autoincrement = 0;` outside the for lopp. `autoincrement++;` each itteration inside the for loop. You might even be able to use a for-loop where the running counter `i` would be your autoincrement.

Comment: Got it fixed thanks everyone

Comment: Technically, this should be done in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `autoincrement` is scoped to the `foreach` loop block so it is allocated and released each iteration.  Declare the variable outside of the `foreach` loop (or you can use a `for` loop):

```
for( var i = 0; i < dt_Table.Rows.Count; ++i )
{
    var dr = dt_Table.Rows[i];
    var nombre = dr["Nombre"].ToString();

    <tr>
        <td align="center">@i</td>
        <td align="center">@nombre</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick answer, can't believe I could't figure this out

```
@{
    int autoincrement = 1;
    dt_Table = ds_Set.Tables[1];
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt_Table.Rows)
    {

        string nombre = dr["Nombre"].ToString();



        <tr>
            <td align="center">@(autoincrement++)</td>
            <td align="center">@nombre</td>
        </tr>

    }
}
```